# module is declared in two place

Tags: angular, ionic2

I built an app in debug mode the app works fine on device but when I try to make a release build I get this type of error:

[image]

I generate a page using ionic generate page my-page
it has 4 files

- my-page.html
- my-page.scss
- my-page.module.ts
- my-page.ts

And I declared this in app.ts file:

```
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { my-page} from 'pages/my-page.my-page';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        my-page
      ]
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
          MyApp,
        my-page
       ]

      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Could someone suggest me how to fix this and make a production build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a module, and my-page is likely declared in that module.  On top of this, it appears as if your import path is incorrect `import { my-page } from 'pages/my-page'` is probably the location you're looking for.

If the component is part of `declarations` in your *my-page.module.ts* you need to remove `my-page` from your entry components, and it's likely you don't need it in declarations either. Instead import the module:

```
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { MyPageModule } from 'pages/my-page.module'; // this assumes '.my-page.module.ts' has 'export class MyPageModule { }' at the end.

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp
      ]
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MyPageModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
          MyApp
       ]

      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```